# How to access a 'private' service of Kubernetes in browser?

Tags: docker, service, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a Kubernetes cluster in GKE. The first thing I tried was deploying the cluster, creating a deployment, a service (type: NodePort) and I've created an Ingress above my service.

I was able to visit my pod using a public IP now. This is all working fine but now I want to create a cluster from which I can access the services in my browser using a private IP, but I don't want others to access it.

I've created a new cluster but I've disabled the HTTP loadbalancing addon. So this isn't created inside my cluster. Now I made a new deployment, created a new service which type is `ClusterIP`.

Now I seem to have a private service, but how can I access this in my browser?

Is it possible to create a VPN solution in GKE to connect to the cluster and get some IP from inside the cluster which will allow me to access the private services in my cluster?

If I'm misunderstanding something, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: I did a similar thing, but in AWS. Maybe you can adapt it for GKE. I deployed a service of type LoadBalancer with an annotation that made AWS to deploy a private ELB. This way my services are reachable only when I am connected to my AWS cluster through a VPN

Comment: Hm interesting. I know it's possible to create a service with annotation ILB. I will try to read a bit more about this.

Comment: @whites11 Are you deploy!ing each service as type Loadbalancer or only one to access the cluster?

Comment: In my case I have only one private load balancer that serves my ingress controller and all other services are exposed via an Ingress